# VBA Script to import text files into single excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a VBA button on a spreadsheet to import all text files into that spreadsheet.

I'd ideally like the filename written to column 1 and text file contents to column 2. The text files contain a single line of information.

I have the contents working below but can't figure out how to get the file name next to that.

```
    Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Dim FileText As TextStream
    Dim TextLine As String
    Dim Items() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    ' Get a FileSystem object
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    ' get the directory you want
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\DataExport")

    ' set the starting point to write the data to
    Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)

    ' Loop thru all files in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        ' Open the file
        Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

        ' Read the file one line at a time
        Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
            TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

            ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
            Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

            ' Put data on one row in active sheet
            For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
                cl.Offset(0, i).Value = Items(i)
            Next

            ' Move to next row
            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop

        ' Clean up
        FileText.Close
    Next file

    Set FileText = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo,

I hope it is as you wanted it:

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\DataExport")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Write file-name
    cl.Value = file.Name

    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, 1 + i).Value = Items(i)
        Next

        ' Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```